# Does Mac OS X support VHCI (Virtual USB host controller) models?

Tags: macos, usb, driver, device

Does anyone know if Mac OS X supports the VHCI model that Windows supports?. The VHCI stands for Virtual Host controller. Basically, using this model, I can write a driver that exposes another USB controller to the operating system.

I am comfortable writing Mac OS X drivers. I am just not sure if Mac OS X supports this model and if so, where would I look for the relevant headers in the IOKit?.

Thanks,
Rama

I have looked online and could not find answers to my question

Comment: Did you find the answer?